# TypeError: Cannot read property 'allMarkdownRemark' of undefined - on Gatsby

Tags: undefined, gatsby

I have an image of the problem and the piece of code where I am having the problem.
Any help?

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "gatsby-link";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

import "../styles/blog-listing.css";

export default function Index({ data })
{

const { edges: posts } = data.allMarkdownRemark;

  return (
    <div className="blog-posts">
      {posts
        .filter(post => post.node.frontmatter.title.length > 0)
        .map(({ node: post }) => {
          return (
            <div className="blog-post-preview" key={post.id}>
              <h1>
                <Link to={post.frontmatter.path}>{post.frontmatter.title}</Link>
              </h1>
              <h2>{post.frontmatter.date}</h2>
              <p>{post.excerpt}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: before 'const { edges: posts } = data.allMarkdownRemark;' you can add a validation check like `if (!data) { return null };`

Comment: Thank you very much, Jee Mok. Spot on!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `graphql` query which selects markdown files. Query results will be passed as `data` object in the `props`. You can try adding a query like this at the end of the file :

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogQuery() {
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: {order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date]}) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 400)
          id
          timeToRead
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            category
            date(formatString: "YYYYMMDD")
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
`
```